# Would it be correct to replace ۃ with ہ in Urdu?

Tags: arabic, hindustani, urdu

What would be the right way to normalize the Arabic *Tāʼ marbūṭah* character in Urdu loan words from Arabic/Farsi?

Would it be correct to replace `ۃ` with `ہ` (gōl hē)?
Or can we replace `ۃ` with `ط` (t̤oʼē) ?

What is the general norm for normalization?

---

Please also note that I have not asked if I can replace `ۃ` with `ت` (tē) because it could create ambiguities [as described here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/urdu-arabic-%D9%80%DB%83-to-%D9%80%DB%81-or-%D8%AA-patterns-different-meanings.2868086/).

Comment: There's one more option: leaving the Arabic _Tāʼ marbūṭah_ as it is in Arabic, with the two dots.

Comment: Indeed, but it seems that isn't the case when writing Arabic-derived words in Urdu. Example: [`جمهورية`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%AC%D9%85%D9%87%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A9#Arabic) to [`جمہوریہ`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%AC%D9%85%DB%81%D9%88%D8%B1%DB%8C%DB%81#Urdu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe Arabic `ۃ` is ever replaced with `ط` (t̤oʼē) in Urdu.

Arabic `ۃ` is usually replaced with `ہ` (gōl hē) with the exception of a few well-known terms, such as: `صلوٰۃ` `زکوٰۃ`. Examples of Arabic words where it's replaced with `ہ` include `کلمہ`, `طیّبہ`, `زیادہ`.

If you know Urdu well enough, you can read some discussion on this [message board](https://www.urduweb.org/mehfil/threads/%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AF%D9%88-%DA%A9%DB%92-%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A8.53519/page-2) which also points to some grammar reference.